# Rotate the model when the axes in the edit mode are different from the object mode

Tags: modeling

I have downloaded this model from sketchfab
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/animated-rat-bone-rigged-l-poly-free-afeeccb10aa8457e9008558e841eda1e
I then imported the model in blender. I tried to rotate the model in object mode around the z axes with 90. It appears to be rotated in object mode. But when I switch to edit mode, it has a different orientation. I try to export the model in .egg file format but the orientation is wrong. Why are the axes in edit and object mode different and how can I achieve the desired orientation.

This is the object mode
[image]

This is the edit mode
[image]

Comment: hard to understand what's happening, in what way the axes are different? could you please show some screenshots?

Comment: I added photos to clarify. What I mean is that the orientation of model with respect to axes is diiferent in both modes

Comment: In the second image, I can see that you are in edit mode for the armature. That would indicate that the armature is rotating the model.

Comment: So how can I make the object and edit mode similar. I didn't create the model, so I don't know why they are different in the first place. Sorry if the question is silly, but I'm a blender noob.